# Given a pointer,how does gdb get its type?

Tags: c, gdb

How does gdb know the pointer points to a `int` or `struct` or any other data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdb` knows the type of a pointer variable in your code by reading the debugging information (a.k.a. symbol table) that's embedded in your executable when you compile with the debug option (`-g`).

Comment: Debugging information is stored in the symbol table only in some (very old) object file formats (such as COFF). On most modern OSes, the debugging info is *not* stored in the symbol table.

Answer (score 7):

from: [Examining the Symbol Table](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_109.html)

> whatis expr
>
> Print the data type of expression expr. expr is not actually evaluated, and any side-effecting operations (such as assignments or function calls) inside it do not take place. See section Expressions.

---

> ptype expr
>
> ptype
>
> Print a description of the type of expression expr. ptype differs from whatis by printing a detailed description, instead of just the name of the type. For example, for this variable declaration:

```
struct complex {double real; double imag;} v;
```

the two commands give this output:

```
(gdb) whatis v
 type = struct complex
(gdb) ptype v
 type = struct complex {
    double real;
    double imag;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

gdb can't know, unless the pointer came from a variable or expression for which the type can be determined.

If gdb is given 0x4567789, it has no idea what that might point to. But if an int *p has that value, gdb can deference that and give you what that address contains.

Comment: how does gdb deference type of `p`?

Comment: OK, that's a good question. gdb looks at the debug information (usually DWARF) in the object file containing the executable (usually an ELF file). If it sees that the instruction pointer is a 0xXXXXX and that is within the function foo, it looks for the variables that are defined in foo and sees that your asking for *p. It sees that p is an int* and reads the memory at the address contained in p (sometimes that's 4 bytes) and interprets the result as an integer. gdb depends entirely on the debug information in the object file.